# Parameter 0 of constructor in serviceImpl. Jpa, Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Всем привет, пытаюсь запустить код,но почему-то,ничего не получается, падает с ошибкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В интернете не смог найти ответа, ничего не помогает. Мой код:

Repository:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student,Long> {

}
```

StudentServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

   private final StudentRepository repository;

   private final StudentMapper mapper;

   @Override
   public StudentResponseDTO createCompany(StudentRequestDTO studentRequestDTO) {
      Student student = mapper.studentRequestDtoToStudent(studentRequestDTO);
      repository.save(student);
      return mapper.studentToStudentResponseDto(student);
    }
  }
```

Student(Entity):

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "department")
private String department;

@Column(name = "group")
private String group;

}
```

Pom dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно полный stacktrace в текстовом виде увидеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло следующее. Удаление зависимостей mapstucr + класса mapper.
Потом я переименовал столбец group в entity, ведь есть оператор group у postgresql.Всем спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Такое может быть из-за 6-й версии hibernate-core. Насколько я понимаю, её пока не поддерживает Spring.

А вообще, hibernate-core (5-х версий), spring-boot-autoconfigure и persistence-api уже есть в подключенных стартерах.

Comment: То есть, hibernate-core (5-х версий), spring-boot-autoconfigure и javax.persistence-api, есть изначально в spring-boot-starter и в spring-boot-starter-data-jpa?

Comment: После смены версии,ничего не помогло, удаление зависимостей тоже

Comment: Да, к слову, spring-boot-starter тоже есть в spring-boot-starter-web).

Comment: Только, как выяснилось, стартер содержит зависимость jakarta.persistence-api, а не javax.persistence-api.